# how determine ZF2 the path to controller action phtml

Tags: zend-framework2

There is a controller:

```
module/ModuleName/src/ModuleName/Controller/SubFolder/ControllerNameController
```

With action:

```
doSomethingAction()
```

In module.config.php:

```php
'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'ModuleName' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
]
```

In one of my projects ZF2 search the .phtml file like this:

```
view/module-name/sub-folder/controller-name/do-something.phtml
```

This is ok for me.

But in another project ZF2 search the .phtml file like this:

```
view/module-name/controller-name/do-something.phtml
```

This is not ok for me, because the controller name must be unique in the module.

Where is the reason for this behavior?

Why does ZF2 ignore the folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the two different projects using different versions of ZF2. I would guess that the project where the sub-folder is included in the view template path is a version of ZF2 post 2.3.2 and the project where it is not included is a version pre 2.3.2.

You can take a look at the pull request here: https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/pull/5670

If you are running a pre 2.3.2 application I would suggest you should update your ZF2 dependency to the latest stable release

There was also some breaking changes merged in this pull request which I believe are part of ZF3:

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/pull/139

Which could be of use if you are already using a later version of the framework

Comment: my composer.json has `"zendframework/zendframework": "~2.5"` and was successfully updated. And: Zend\Version\Version::VERSION = '2.5.1'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. It was the missing `__NAMESPACE__` variable in the routes.